# how desktop files sync with webserver in Gwt web application with RPC call?

Tags: jakarta-ee, gwt, uibinder

According to my project req whenever we add files/folders to a specific folder in our local machine that data sholud sync with webserver & display on Web UI automatically without pressing refresh button...

for this i'm using GWT UI-Binder, Java EE and MySQL DB.
            would u plz help me any one with this concern.....

```
         Thanking U...........in Advance
```

Comment: Can you mention what you have tried?

Comment: Is your webserver running on the same machine where the files are added or is it a different machine over the network

Answer (score 0):

I think you will not be able to do it, because browser has limited access to file system and javascript runs in the browser sandbox. Probably you can try to use applet for uploading file to server and some ways to push notification to client side.